# CSS optimizer based on HTML structure

Tags: html, css, optimization

I'm looking for any kind of CSS optimizer that optimize CSS regards to HTML structure. I would like to have optimizator better than CSSTiny because HTML is completly known.

Here is an example.
For complete HTML like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="id1">
      some text here
    </div>
    <div id="id2">
      another text here
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which uses CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#id1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#id2 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

CSS Optimizator should produce:

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
}

div {
    margin: 10px auto;
}

#id1 {
    font-size: 14px;
}

#id2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

or even more, ideal output (changed by @animuson feedback):

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
}

div {
    margin: 10px auto;
}

div:last {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}    

#id1 {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Usign of CSS shorthands is irrelevant - it is simple and it already exists. I'm asking for some extremely smart CSS optimizer. Bonus is if it works with collection of HTML files instead of one file, which uses same CSS.

Thank you for your answers!
Boris.

Comment: How would a CSS optimizer ever get from the second CSS to the third? They are not magical like they know exactly how you're going to use ID 'id2' in your documents. Also `body { font-size: 12px }` is completely different from `div { font-size: 12px }`...

Comment: There is no magic, I wrote that HTMLs are finite and you know how "#id2" is used. Optimization from `body { font-size: 12px }` should be used because content of body element are divs only and this definition reduce CSS size. This optimization is result of deeper analysis of CSS+HTML.

Comment: The problem with that is you're then saying that only divisions can be in the body because the font-size won't be applied to any other elements. You're *over-optimizing* your CSS and actually setting unnecessary restrictions on what you can do without modifying your CSS again.

Comment: Yes, you're right it is over-optimized. This kind of optimization is really unnecessary. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, if only programs could do that, we could just click a button and a website would be made.

Since we are not in this utopia yet, we **still** have to optimize our own code. Which is the **proper** way of doing things.

If that code comes from a generator, improve that. If you write it, well... you know.

Comment: -1. It's far from an "utopia" to have something like this. It's just a case of defining rules (for example, the margin-* ←→ margin: correspondence) and running the right algorithm over them. As an example, see [A Genetic approach to CSS compression](http://friggeri.net/blog/a-genetic-approach-to-css-compression/) (and yes, I know that this didn't exist when this answer was written, but I'm pretty sure that we haven't jumped halfway to utopia in less than an year).

Answer (score 1):

Well, closest thing to that you want. that I know is: https://github.com/afelix/csso

It can do some smart optimizations, like:

- Merging blocks with identical selectors
- Merging blocks with identical properties
- Removal of overridden properties
- Removal of overridden shorthand properties
- Removal of repeating selectors
- Partial merging of blocks
- Partial splitting of blocks

See manual: https://github.com/afelix/csso/blob/master/MANUAL.en.md

But it still works only with css files, it didn't parse html structure and optimize on that.